# Forward current message as an attachment then delete the original message

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to forward a current message as an attachment and then delete the original message.

When I run the macro the message is not deleted and I receive an email from "System Administrator" that the message was un-deliverable.

If I comment out the line `.DeleteAfterSubmit = True` the message is sent but not deleted.

```vb
Dim objAttachment As Attachment
Dim strAttachment As String
Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
strAttachment = ""
 
For Each objAttachment In objItem.Attachments
    strAttachment = strAttachment & " " & objAttachment.DisplayName ' FileName
Next

With objMsg
    .Attachments.Add objItem, olEmbeddeditem
    .Subject = objItem.Subject & " " & objItem.To
    .To = "email@outlook.com"
    .Body = "From: " & objItem.Sender & vbNewLine & _
            "Sent: " & objItem.ReceivedTime & vbNewLine & _
            "To: " & objItem.To & vbNewLine & _
            "CC: " & objItem.CC & vbNewLine & _
            "Subject: " & objItem.Subject & vbNewLine & _
            "Attachment: " & strAttachment & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            objItem.Body
    .DeleteAfterSubmit = True
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: i think that it only prevents saving in _Sent Items_

Comment: objMsg.Delete or objItem.Delete depending on which one you want to delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Should be **`objItem.Delete`** outside **`With...End With`***

```
With objMsg
    .Attachments.Add objItem, olEmbeddeditem
    .subject = objItem.subject & " " & objItem.To
    .To = "email@outlook.com"
    .Body = "From: " & objItem.sender & vbNewLine & _
            "Sent: " & objItem.ReceivedTime & vbNewLine & _
            "To: " & objItem.To & vbNewLine & _
            "CC: " & objItem.CC & vbNewLine & _
            "Subject: " & objItem.subject & vbNewLine & _
            "Attachment: " & strAttachment & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     objItem.Body
    .Send
End With

objItem.Delete
```